# R shiny: errors when running the code via another computer

Tags: r, shiny, character-encoding

I have recently made a R shiny application. Due to broken lap, I needed to run the code in another one but many problems of syntax appear and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
ui <- navbarPage(title ="ESA Data Explorer", theme = shinytheme("united"),
             #### About us Shiny menu #####
             navbarMenu("About us",
                        tabPanel("The lab",
                                 h3(strong("Who are we?")),
                                 h4("We are a multidisciplinary research group of the Université Libre de Bruxelles,
                        which includes biologists, microbiologists,
                           ecological modelers and bioengineers. Our activities focus on the study
                           and modeling of the structure and functioning of aquatic systems 
                           (rivers, lakes, estuaries and coastal waters) and their response to natural
                           and anthropogenic changes. Our methodology involves and combines field observations,
                           process level studies under field and laboratory-controlled conditions and ecological
                           and biogeochemical modeling."),
                                 h3(strong("Our main research domains are:")),
                                 h4("- Coastal eutrophication"),
                                 h4("- Marine biogeochemical cycles and climatic gases"),
                                 h4("- Bacterial ecology of surface waters"),
                                 h4("- Microbiological quality of aquatic
                        ecosystems"),
                                 h4("- Microbiological aspect of drinking water production and distribution"),
                                 h5("More informations about the lab available",
                                    a("here", href = "http://esa.ulb.ac.be/")),
                                 br(),
                                 br(),
                                 br(),
                                 br(),
                                 br(),
                                 br()



                        )))
```

The error that i receive is :

Error : unexpected symbol in:
"                                     br()
ui"

When I delete this part to run the next one of the ui function, I get the same message but in a different manner. It is always referred as unexpected symbol in a part of my text while everything looks correct. About the server function, everything is working perfectly. It seems like  R can't read correctly this code, maybe due to different encoding, or because R is in a different version, I really don't know. Could you please help me to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the two packages that have

```
br()
```

as an option on the new laptop.
(use ?br to see if that is the case)

Try to specify which one you are calling via.

```
shiny::br()
```

or

```
htmltools::br()
```

For your code your would need-

```
...
shiny::br(),
shiny::br(),
shiny::br()
...(for example)
```

This usually helps happens to me when I forget to specifity select in dplyr.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, htmltools is not installed in my R. I still have the same message error: Error : unexpected symbol in: " shiny::br() ui". I don't know if it could help you, but my R is in version 3.6.1 and when it automatically asks to download missing packages (because of new lap), it says that packages have been compiled with version 3.6.2. Do you think it may be caused by this? I'm also wondering if I should rewrite the whole code manually in a new R script.

Comment: I would just run `update_packages` anyway just to be safe.  But also you could just try to make the hr() instead of br() as a way to jerryrig your way around it for now.  I mean if you just need it to work that might be an option. Otherwise I am not sure I would know what to do. Sorry.

Comment: I've just solved the problem but it is really weird. I only had to write texts in ONE LINE for h4(), label =,... functions instead of pressing enter to make the text in 4,5,... lines. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem, I didnt really help, but im glad you figured it out.